# Iterate over two hashes, sum values and create third hash with new keys

Tags: ruby, hash

I have two array of hashes and I'm trying to create third array of hashes adding each value from `dates` to each `times` value.

```
dates=[{a:­1},{a:2},{­a:3}]
times=[{f:7,t:8}­,{f:9,t­:10},{f:11,t:12­}]
```

I know in case of two single hashes

```
dates={a:1}
times={f:7,t:8}
```

I can do

```
a=[]
h={}
h[:from]=d­ates[:a]+times[:f]
h[:to]=dates[:a]+times­[:t]
a<<h

=> [{:from=>8, :to=>9}]
```

How do I iterate to make this happen for my array of hashes above, please?

My desired result is `[{:from=>8,:to=>9},{:from=>10,:to=>11}, {:from=>12,:to=>13},{:from=>9,:to=>10},{:from=>11,:to=>12},{:from=>13,:to=>14},{:from=>10,:to=>11},{:from=>12,:to=>13},{:from=>14,:to=>15}]`

Comment: Your code contains several (invisible) soft hypens which turn into `-` upon copy/paste. Please fix it.

Comment: @Stefan I'm sorry, please, see my update above. In my example I need to get back array of 9 hashes. Basically each `a` has to be summed with each value from `times`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your desired result is `[{:from=>8,:to=>9},{:from=>10,:to=>11}..]`, I assume, that [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) is what you're looking for.

Fortunately, there's [Array#product](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-product) in `Ruby`, that's why the solution is as simple as this:

```
dates=[{a:1},{a:2},{a:3}]
times=[{f:7,t:8},{f:9,t:10},{f:11,t:12}]

result = dates.product(times).map do |date, time|
  {from: date[:a] + time[:f], to: date[:a] + time[:t]}
end

puts result
```

Comment: Thank you! As I'm still learning Ruby this is very informative and helpful.

Comment: @matiss you should really read the documentation for the classes (and modules) you are working with (`Array`, `Hash` and `Enumerable` in this case). It contains many useful examples.

Comment: @Stefan All of those 3 docs are opened all the time and I read them. It's just I still don't quite understand how they all play together. In this case `product` is under Array and `map` is under `Enumerable`, however I think I'm working with Hash, so I'm focusing what can I do with Hash :)

Answer (score 1):

```
dates.product(times).map do |d,t|
  n = d[:a]
  t.transform_values { |v| v + n }
end
  #=> [{:f=>8, :t=> 9}, {:f=>10, :t=>11}, {:f=>12, :t=>13},
  #    {:f=>9, :t=>10}, {:f=>11, :t=>12}, {:f=>13, :t=>14},
  #    {:f=>10, :t=>11}, {:f=>12, :t=>13}, {:f=>14, :t=>15}]
```

The first step is

```
dates.product(times)
  #=> [[{:a=>1}, {:f=>7, :t=>8}], [{:a=>1}, {:f=>9, :t=>10}], [{:a=>1}, {:f=>11, :t=>12}],
  #    [{:a=>2}, {:f=>7, :t=>8}], [{:a=>2}, {:f=>9, :t=>10}], [{:a=>2}, {:f=>11, :t=>12}],
  #    [{:a=>3}, {:f=>7, :t=>8}], [{:a=>3}, {:f=>9, :t=>10}], [{:a=>3}, {:f=>11, :t=>12}]]
```

See [Array#product](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-product) and [Hash#transform_values](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values), the latter having made its debut in v2.4.